# Select table using case statement

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
if v_id = 1 then
select a.id, a.value from table_a a;
elsif v_id = 2 then
select b.id, b.value from table_b b;
else
select c.id, c.value from table_c c;
end if;
```

Here i want to select table name using case statement **after from clause**

```
case when v_id = 1 then
table_a
when v_id = 2 then 
table_b
else then
table_c
end as t
```

**Is it possible??**
if possible then please help me with this query

Answer (score 2):

You could use `UNION ALL`:

```
select a.id, a.value 
from table_a a
where v_id = 1
union all
select b.id, b.value 
from table_b b
where v_id = 2
union all
select c.id, c.value 
from table_c c
where v_id = 3;
```

Keep in mind that each `SELECT` should have the the same number of columns and appropriate types.

---

Another possibility is custom crafted SQL query and dynamic SQL.

Comment: I already aware about dynamic SQL with this issue. But here i want to use case after from clause to select the table. If possible then tell me the way or does oracle support that format i have written?

Comment: @B.Khan The format you proposed i.e. `FROM CASE` is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want but you just need to copy the statements where table_a and table_b are:

```
case when v_id = 1 then
select a.id, a.value from table_a a;
when v_id = 2 then 
select b.id, b.value from table_b b;
else
select c.id, c.value from table_c c;
end as t
```

This will create table t with the id and value as columns from the tables. If you want all of the table replace "a.id, a.value" with "*".

Note: The syntax might be incorrect:

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN v_id = 1 THEN a.id
            WHEN v_id = 2 then b.id
            ELSE c.id END AS ID,
       CASE WHEN v_id = 1 THEN a.value
            WHEN v_id = 2 then b.value
            ELSE c.value END AS VALUE
FROM a,b,c
```

And it must be return a table with 2 column ID AND VALUE, depending the v_id value.